# How to get index current validated struct inside custom validation

Tags: go, validation

I am using this library: https://github.com/go-playground/validator

This ilustrate my problem:

```
type Parent struct {
  Childs []Child `validate:"dive"`
}

type Child struct {
  JustAField string `validate:"customValidation"`
}

func customValidation(fl validator.FieldLevel) bool {
   // here I want to get the index of child
   // which currently being validated
}

errs := validate.Struct(Parent)
```

I cannot find a method to get current index of child inside customValidation,

But if there is an error, somehow the library itself knows the index:

```
for _, e := range errs {
  e.Namespace() // Parent.childs[0].just_a_field
}
```

does anyone know how to get the index?

thanks

Answer (score -1):

> does anyone know how to get the index?

No, simply because this information doesn't exist.

If you need that you have to apply the validation to the Parent: Each child doesn't even *know* that it "lives" in a slice.